# Deriving SHM equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

i have derived SHM equation till here
$$\sin\left( \frac{\sqrt k}{\sqrt m}\cdot t \right)$$

Now all the solutions (youtube and textbook) I'm looking are just stating intuitively $\frac{k}{m} = \text{constant}$ which is true. But why only $\Omega^2$ and not some other constant? Now if i assume the constant is $\Omega$ then
$$\frac{k}{m} = \frac{4π^2}{T^2}$$
while if i just assume some other constant then equation just becomes $\sin(\text{constant}\cdot t)$

Comment: Derivation must start from the equation of motion, which defines what is what exactly. It appears that you are trying to see why the quoted constant is angular frequency by just staring at the solution. Unless you use physics in the latter approach, arriving at the conclusion is difficult. So, either start from the EOM, or try plotting how an oscillating trajectory looks like and compare coefficient with $\omega$. Also remember the dimensions.

Comment: @physicophilic i started derivation d^2x/dt^2 +(k/m)*x = 0 and reached ((√/√)∗)

Comment: I see. My bad to suggest the first point in this case. Plot the solution, and note, that when time increases by $2\pi\sqrt{m/k}$, the function returns to the point you had started from. In other words, the particle with mass m is oscillating with a period $T=2\pi\sqrt{m/k}$. Now, one defines frequency of oscillation $\nu=1/T$. That means the angular frequency must be $\sqrt{k/m}$.

Comment: are you suggesting that when t=2√ . the function returns to starting point because then t is coming dimensionally incorrect .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is think about the function
$$
\sin( c t )
$$
where $c$ is a constant. For example, you could plot the function on a graph, or find out at what time the function repeats. You will find it repeats when $ct = 2\pi$ and $4\pi,\;6\pi$ etc. So this means that, for this function, the period is $2\pi/c$. This also means that the frequency in cycles per unit time is $c/2\pi$, and the angular frequency (radians per unit time) is $c$. We ordinarily use the symbol $\omega$ or $\Omega$ for angular frequency. Therefore the function is
$$
\sin(\Omega t)
$$
This means that the mathematical move where you set
$$
\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{m}} = \Omega
$$
is not an arbitrary choice which could have been something else; rather it is a move in which you *recognise* what role $\sqrt{k/m}$ is playing in the function you have got.

Answer (score 1):

> i started derivation d^2x/dt^2 +(k/m)*x = 0 and reached
>   ((√/√)∗)

But this isn't the entire solution is it?  If $X$ is the maximum displacement, then $$x(t) = X\sin(\sqrt{k/m}\cdot t + \phi)$$
is a solution such that the initial position is

$$x(0) = X\sin(\phi)$$

and the initial velocity is

$$\dot{x}(0) = X\sqrt{k/m}\cos(\phi)$$

---

> But why only $\Omega^2$ and not some other constant?

[Simple harmonic motion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleHarmonicMotion.html) is of the form

$$x(t) = X\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\cdot t + \phi\right)$$

where $T$ is the *period* of the motion, i.e., the time over which the motion completes one *cycle*.  The [*angular frequency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) is related to the period as so

$$\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$$

thus, for the $x(t)$ given above,

$$\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$$

Comment: ()=sin(2⋅+) is the equation i am deriving. how can i already use derived equation to assume that √k/√m.What i am saying is that if we suppose we don't know the equation of shm and deriving it for the first time then there will be no equation to compare and prove that  =√/

Comment: @Who, I honestly don't understand what you're looking for after reading your comment above.  But, consider this:  (1) Given that differential equation, the general solution *is* the sinusoidal $x(t)$ I give in my answer. (2) The [instantaneous angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantaneous_phase_and_frequency#Instantaneous_frequency) $\omega$ of a sinusoid  $f(t) = \sin\left(\theta(t)\right)$ is *defined* by $\omega\equiv\dot\theta(t)$. (3) Since $\theta(t) = \sqrt{k/m}\cdot t + \phi$ here, it follows that $\omega = \sqrt{k/m}$, a constant.

Answer (score 0):

With $\hat i$ a unit vector, a definition of simple harmonic motion might go like this.

The motion of a particle is simple harmonic if

- the acceleration of the particle, $\vec a$, is proportional to the displacement of the particle from a fixed point, $\vec x$
- the acceleration of the particle is always directed towards the fixed
  point

From the first statement $\vec a \propto \vec x \Rightarrow a\,\hat i \propto x \,\hat i$ where $a$ and $x$ are components of acceleration and displacement in the $\hat i$ direction.

From the second statement $\vec a = -c \, \vec x \Rightarrow a\, \hat  i = c \, x\,(-\hat i)$ where $c$ ia a constant which must be positive.

How might one ensure that $c$ is positive?
By defining $c=\Omega^2$ where $\Omega$ is a constant. which results in the equation $a = - \Omega^2 \,x$.

Doing this also means that there is a simple relationship between the constant $\Omega$ and the period of the oscillation $T$ which is $T = \frac{2 \pi}{\Omega}$.